# Inserting value from a combobox into a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am attempting to insert the record into m sql database. My very first value is 1 then 1001. My insert will place the first value which is 1 correctly but 1001 and beyond it returns null. How can I change this to read the value and not use the index since it does not go in sequential order?

Insert Method:

```
SqlCommand addJob = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO JobNumber ( JobID, CustomerID, JobDescription, IsActive) VALUES ( @JobID, (SELECT @CustomerID FROM Customer C WHERE C.CustomerID = @CustomerID), @JobDescription, @IsActive)", dbConn);
addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobID", Convert.ToInt32(jobidTextBox.Text));
addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Convert.ToInt32(customeridComboBox.SelectedIndex) + 1);
addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobDescription", jobdescriptionTextBox.Text);
addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isactiveCheckBox.Checked);
dbConn.Open();
addJob.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selected text/ selected item property of the combo-box instead of the index.

Answer (score 0):

you should  retrieve your text item like this

```
addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Convert.ToInt32(customeridComboBox.Items[customeridComboBox.SelectedIndex+ 1] );
```

Comment: are you  sure that you have a selected index

Comment: I'm using a previous example I used where the records were 1,2,3,4,5. This is 1,1001,1002 which is think what the problem is.

Comment: which  exception you have got the message please

Comment: Input string was not in correct format. The combobox displays example: 1 - Name

Comment: are you using wpf or winforms